# Can I configure nvim-qt to look like a terminal?

Tags: neovim, neovim-qt

In gVim there's `guioptions` which lets you disable the gui-specific features. I'm curious if I can configure this in Neovim somehow.

If it can't be done across the board, what I want most is it be able to change the keyword completion menu, as it's not obeying the `Pmenu` highlight group and the gray on gray is very hard to see.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Popup menu in neovim-qt is controlled by `GuiPopupmenu` command.

You should add it to you `ginit.vim`:

```
GuiPopupmenu 0
```

[image]

PS:

It is not documented that well, I've found it somewhere in github issues.
You can also try look into neovim-qt shim layer to find out what else is there:

[image]